# How to turn an app into a kernel-mode running code?

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, windows-kernel

I have C application that determines when power is on\off on my laptop.
It works only when I open this .exe file

Is there a way to make it work in kernel mode?
meaning I don't want to run the .exe but just turn on the laptop and recieve a msg about the power when power is low.

here is my .exe :

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";




 // Step 4: the Window Procedure
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
short x ;

SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS status; 


switch(msg)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;

case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
                switch (wParam)
                    {
                        case PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE :
                            x = GetSystemPowerStatus(&status);
                            if (x > 0) // function succeeded
                                {
                                    if (status.ACLineStatus == 1)
                                    {
                                        printf("power is off");
                                        MessageBox(NULL, "power is on" , "NOTICE" ,MB_OK );
                                    }
                                    else if (status.ACLineStatus == 0)
                                    {
                                        printf("power is on");
                                        MessageBox(NULL, "power is off" , "NOTICE" ,MB_OK );
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        printf("unknown");
                                        MessageBox(NULL, "unknown status" , "ERROR" ,MB_OK);
                                    }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                LPSTR str = "function failed in providing information";
                                MessageBox(NULL , str, "ERROR", MB_OK);
                                }
                            break;
                        case PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE:
                            x = GetSystemPowerStatus(&status);
                            if (x > 0) // function succeeded
                            {
                                if (status.ACLineStatus == 1)
                                {
                                    printf("power is off");
                                    MessageBox(NULL, "power is on" , "NOTICE" ,MB_OK );
                                }
                                else if (status.ACLineStatus == 0)
                                {
                                    printf("power is on");
                                    MessageBox(NULL, "power is off" , "NOTICE" ,MB_OK );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    printf("unknown");
                                    MessageBox(NULL, "unknown status" , "ERROR" ,MB_OK);
                                }
                            }

                            break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox ( NULL , "nothing" , "------" , MB_OK);
                    }
                break;
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if (wParam == MK_LBUTTON)
        MessageBox(NULL, "mouse was clicked", "check", MB_OK);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

 int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {
WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;
HPOWERNOTIFY notification_1;

//Step 1: Registering the Window Class
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;  //signing to the updating service of the operating system
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

// Step 2: Creating the Window
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "The title of my window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(!hwnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

notification_1 = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hwnd, &GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);


ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// Step 3: The Message Loop
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}



return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand why you want to run this code in kernel mode ... Is not enough run as a service ?

You should pack your program as a windows service and then install the service on your system . There is no need to go at the kernel level.